# $H \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ a linear subspace with a dimension of n-1, so $H$ is a null set

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

I'm trying to prove the following:
let $H \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ a linear subspace with a dimension of n-1, so $H$ is a null set.

In our class we were given the definition if a null set as the following; The set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a null set if for each $\varepsilon >0 $ there exists open bricks $ Q_j$ such that $E\subseteq \cup_jQ_j$ and $\sum_jvol(Q_j) <\varepsilon $

In addition, we know that the countable union of null sets is a null set, so what i'm trying to do is to show that H is actually a union of null sets, but i'm struggling to see how.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is not true that the union of null sets is always a null set. Just think that $\mathbb R=\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb R^n}\{x\}$ and that each singleton is a null set.

Comment: First try to break it into simple cases. Can you prove that any line through origin has two dimensional Lebesgue measure $0$ ?

Comment: thank you! i edited my question, and now it's a countable union of null sets

Comment: Consider $n=3$ and $H=\Bbb R^2\times \{0\}.$  For $n\in \Bbb N$ let $B_n$ be a finite collection of bricks of $\Bbb R^3$ such that $\sum_{b\in B_n}vol(b)<\epsilon \cdot 2^{-n-1}$ and $\cup B_n\supset \{(x,y,0):x^2+y^2\le n^2\},$ which is possible if the heights of the bricks are small enough.  Or we could show that $H_n=^{def}\{(x,y,0):x^2+y^2\le n^2\}$ is null for each $n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Some Tips to Get You Started**

> . . . the union of null sets is a null set, so what i'm trying to do is to show that H is actually a union of null sets, but i'm struggling to see how.

This is incorrect. Consider the union of singletons. $$\bigcup_{x \in \mathbb R^d} \{x\} = \mathbb R^d$$

Each singleton is null but the entire space is not null. The statement  is only correct if the union is countable.

---

**Convenient basis**

You can always rotate the subspace to assume $H = \mathbb R^{d-1} \times\{0\}$ is the span of the first $d-1$ axes. This will make writing down the bricks easier.

This is allowed because rotations map bricks to bricks. Or rather the image of a brick is contained in some other brick. So rotations map null sets to null sets.

---

**An example**

Suppose $d=2$ and $H = \mathbb R \times\{0\}$ is the $x$-axis. Then the positive part of $H$ is contained in the union $B_1 \cup B_2  \cup B_3 \cup \ldots$ for the bricks

$$B_1 = [0,1] \times [0,1]$$

$$B_2 = [1,2] \times [0,1/2]$$

$$B_3 = [2,3] \times [0,1/4]$$

$$ \vdots $$

The geometric series says the volume of the bricks is finite. A similar argument works for higher dimensions.